# Hibernate Exception: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm trying to configure Spring and Hibernate in my project, and I'm having problem at the bean validation. I have this jar in my class path:
`hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar`

I have some tests to query some data from database and it's working fine. Now I add this jar into my class path:
`validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar`

When I try to run the test again, I get this whole stack of exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1704)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:118)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:148)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:109)
    ... 60 more
```

What am I missing? Please let me know if I don't provide enough information.

Update:
- I'm not using Maven. I'm using Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution. One important info that I didn't mention in the question is that I'm using Java 5, not Java 6. I found the answer from this URL: http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator

At the bottom of the article, there are some extra libraries needed to include for Java 5. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 10):

For those who are using Java 6 (J2SE-1.6)

1. Remove jsr-303 (validation-api) from Maven
2. Include **hibernate-validator** like this

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
       <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Clean and build project
   `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 2):

If u use maven then set these dependency.it may be solve this problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>[enter link description here][1]
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Other wise u can use
 First u can download jar and comment your validator code it may be help u to diagnosis problem.

steps to use validation :-
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/

download jar:-
http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator/download.html

Comment: sorry! I'm not using Maven. I'm using tomcat 6

Comment: 4.0.2.GA is an old version of Hibernate Validator. 4.2.0.Final is the latest.